# Is there a way to find out the sharepoint hostname url of the user?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, onedrive

I am using onedrive v8 filepicker in my app in which i have to provide sharepoint url in order to open up the filepicker. I have the access token with me to query from MS Graph API. Can we get the sharepoint host using graph api or any other way to find out the sharepoint url for the user ??

Answer (score 0):

In a SharePoint context, determining the SharePoint hostname (URL) associated with the current user can be achieved using the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) or JavaScript object model. The SharePoint hostname typically includes the domain name, site collection, and any sub-sites. You could refer to following code

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

export default class YourWebPart {
  private context: WebPartContext;

  constructor(context: WebPartContext) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  private getSharePointHostname(): string {
    const siteAbsoluteUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
    return siteAbsoluteUrl;
  }
}
```